# Django: Reverse for 'verify-payment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['course/u/(?P<ref>[^/]+)/$']

Tags: python, django, django-views

i wrote a view to verify payment bbut when i hit the payment button i get this error that say `Reverse for 'verify-payment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['course/u/(?P<ref>[^/]+)/$']`

i know it's a url configuation error, i am not passing in the right arguments but i dont know what to pass in, i already tried `payment.ref`

views.py

```
@login_required
def course_checkout(request, slug):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    user = request.user
    action = request.GET.get('action')
    order = None 
    payment = None 
    error = None 

    try:
        user_course = UserCourse.objects.get(user=user, course=course)
        error = "Congratulations! You are Already Enrolled In This Course"
    except:
        pass 
        amount = None 
        if error is None:
            amount = int((course.price - (course.price * course.discount * 0.01)) * 100)
        if amount == 0:
            userCourse = UserCourse(user=user, course=course)
            userCourse.save()
            return redirect('course:course-content', course.slug) # change this to redirect to my courses page with a button to start course because this course is free

        if action == 'create_payment':
            currency = "NGN"
            notes = {
            "email": user.email,
            "name": user.username
            }
            reciept = f"DexxaEd-{int(time())}"
            order = client.order.create(
                {
                'reciept' : reciept,
                'notes' : notes,
                'amount' : amount,
                'currency' : currency,
                'paystack_public_key' : settings.PAYSTACK_PUBLIC_KEY,
                }
            )

            payment = Payment()
            payment.user = user 
            payment.course = course 
            payment.order_id = order.get('id')
            payment.save()


    context = {
        "course":course,
        "order":order,
        "payment":payment,
        "user":user,
        "error":error,
    }

    return render(request, "course/course-checkout.html", context)


def verify_payment(request: HttpRequest, ref: str) -> HttpResponse:
    payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, ref=ref)
    verified = payment.verify_payment()
    return redirect("userauths:profile")
```

models.py

```
class Payment(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50 , null = False)
    payment_id = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    user_course = models.ForeignKey(UserCourse , null = True , blank = True ,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User ,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course , on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    email = models.EmailField()
    ref = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Payment: {self.course.price}"
    
    def save(self ,*args, **kwargs):
        while not self.ref:
            ref = secrets.token_urlsafe(50)
            objects_with_similar_ref = Payment.objects.filter(ref=ref)
            if not objects_with_similar_ref:
                self.ref = ref 
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def amount_value(self) -> int:
        return self.course.price * 100

    def verify_payment(self):
        paystack = PayStack()
        status, result = paystack,verify_payment(self.ref, self.course.price)
        if status:
            if result['course.price'] / 100 == self.course.price:
            # if result['amount'] / 100 == self.course.price:
                self.verified = True
            self.save()
        if self.verified:
            return True 
        return False
```

urls.py

```
    path('u/<str:ref>/', views.verify_payment, name = 'verify-payment'),
```

course-checkout.html

```
{{ course.price }}
<button id="django-paystack-button" onclick="payWithPayStack()" class="chck-btn22">Make Payment</button>

<script>
    function payWithPaystack() {
        let currency = "USD";
        let plan = "";
        let ref = "{{payment.ref}}";
        let obj = {
            key: "{{ paystack_public_key }}",
            email: "{{ request.user.email }}",
            amount: "{{course.price_value}}",
            ref: ref,
            callback: function (response) {
                window.location.href = "{% url 'course:verify-payment' payment.ref %}";
            },
        };

        if (Boolean(currency)) {
            obj.currency = currency.toUpperCase();
        }
        if (Boolean(plan)) {
            obj.plan = plan;
        }
        var handler = PaystackPop.setup(obj);
        handler.openIframe();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: check value of ``payment.ref``

Comment: Please add the view that corresponds to checkout.html.

Comment: @raphael i have added the view you requested

Comment: @AnkitTiwari it's suppose to get saved in the databse but it shows that `Payment with ID “None” doesn’t exist. Perhaps it was deleted `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with your url configuration, nor the payment.ref, but with the logic in your course_checkout page.  The issue is that a user can land on the course-checkout.html page even if the payment is None, which is what causes the error, because the url is expecting on non empty `<str:ref>`.  My expectation, and apologies if this is not what you are after, is that the only time the user should get to the course-checkout page is if (1) the user is not already registered for the course, or (2) the course is free.  Otherwise, the user should be taken to the course-checkout page (no need to check for `if action == 'create_payment':`, since if (1) or (2) are false, this is the only other option, as I see it).  I haven't tested the code below, but I think this might be the way to do it:

```py
def course_checkout(request, slug):
    course = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    user = request.user
    action = request.GET.get('action')
    order = None 
    payment = None 
    error = None 

    try:
        user_course = UserCourse.objects.get(user=user, course=course)
    except:
        pass

    # User is already registered for course, so go to the course page
    if user_course:
        return redirect('course:course-content', course.slug)

    amount = int((course.price - (course.price * course.discount * 0.01)) * 100)

    # Redirect to my courses page with a button to start course because this course is free
    if amount == 0:
        userCourse = UserCourse(user=user, course=course)
        userCourse.save()
        return redirect('course:course-content', course.slug) 
        
    # User is not registered for the course, and the amount is NOT 0, so send 
    # to the checkout page
    currency = "NGN"
    notes = {
        "email": user.email,
        "name": user.username
    }
    reciept = f"DexxaEd-{int(time())}"
    order = client.order.create(
        {
            'reciept' : reciept,
            'notes' : notes,
            'amount' : amount,
            'currency' : currency,
            'paystack_public_key' : settings.PAYSTACK_PUBLIC_KEY,
        }
    )

    payment = Payment()
    payment.user = user 
    payment.course = course 
    payment.order_id = order.get('id')
    payment.save()

    context = {
        "course":course,
        "order":order,
        "payment":payment,
        "user":user,
        "error":error,
    }

    return render(request, "course/course-checkout.html", context)
```